# What HTTP Status Code should I user when I detect an SQL injection attempt?

Tags: sql-injection, http-status-code-403, http-status-codes

If I detect an SQL injection attempt in PHP (and prevent it from executing), what HTTP status code should I return?

`403 Forbidden` makes sense as the request was attempting a prohibited action. However, I wonder if this gives more information to an attacker that could be used to refine the attack. I wonder if `200 Success` might be better?

EDIT:

Detection always has some value, even if this type of attack is (in theory) completely preventable. There are modern techniques which completely mitigate the risk of SQL Injection. However, there are also many legacy codebases that are vulnerable due to queries that are constructed as strings without proper escaping. That is why the attacks still occur.

In a legacy codebase, I put detection in place so that I could log information about attacks, such as the timing, the source and the target. At a minimum this demonstrates that there is a threat, which can be used to help justify the investment in patching the vulnerabilities.

Patching the entire system will take several months, and there is a central point in the codebase where detection is already working, which by default is returning `200 Success`. Until the whole system can be upgraded, I would like to send the response code that will be the safest. I hoped that there would be a well-known best practice for this but I could not find any.

Comment: Why would anyone "detect an SQL injection attempt" in the first place? What's the use?

Comment: The "use" is for logging, monitoring, alert/notification, quick reaction response, etc. I've professionally used it to identify a known attacker and to set up log tracing to connect to other attacks by the same attacker so we could build a legal case.

Comment: To be clear, even *attempted* SQL Injection attacks on computing resources that you do not own are ILLEGAL in many parts of the world, including everywhere in the United States. It is only "common sense" to detect illegal activity on your own resources.

Comment: 400 Bad Request would fit the best. Or, no response at all. Let them timeout.

Comment: @BryanWilliams I believe whatever "legal cases" are way too far from the scope of this question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense you asked for 'why', you got an answer. Whether or not you think anyone *should* log these is irrelevant.

Comment: Beyond the scope of my question, but sometimes an attacker is local to you, and evidence can be useful.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't try to detect it. Use SQL with placeholders and forget about it.**

It sounds like what you are wanting to do is this (in pseudocode):

```
if ( looks_malicious($username) )
    return "400 Bad Request";
else
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
    execute_my_sql( $sql );
```

That's not the way to do it. You should not be trying to determine if it's a SQL injection attempt, and you should not be trying to sanitize the input.

Instead, you should be doing this:

```
$statement = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?";
execute_my_sql( $sql, $username );
```

Whatever language you are using has the capability to use SQL statements that have placeholders, so that you are not building SQL statements using untrusted data.

They ONLY downside to using placeholders is that you have to learn how to do it. That's it. It is safer, because the SQL library you are using knows more than you do about edge cases. It could well be faster, too, because your RDBMS can keep reusing the same SQL statement.

Once you switch to placeholders, then the answer to "what do I return" doesn't matter. If they try to look up some username that is `Robert'); -- DROP TABLE students; --`, it won't harm you and you'll respond with whatever you respond with if someone looks up another non-existent but non-malicious username.

Comment: In an ideal world, absolutely, and I do know these techniques. The downside is that this legacy codebase is huge and it will take a long time to change it.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against returning an HTTP response when detecting SQL Injection or vulnerability scans. That only serves to make the attacker's job easier.

Answer (score 1):

Consider patching the vulnerability instead.
There is no reason to return a HTTP statuscode based on it.

Comment: Patching is estimated to take several months 

Answer (score 1):

The best practice for validation is to return a response code that is in line with any other input - anything else will leak information to an attacker.  Often, web applications return 200 on all validation errors, with a custom page / error on the same page indicating a validation error has happened.

You want to give attackers as little information about your internal validations - especially if you have specific validation that is detecting SQL injection, since that will be a weakness that can be exploited.  As other answers have mentioned, SQL injections should be prevented via binds / parameterized variables - if you can't do that in the short term, return an error code that makes it look like you are.  But you should make sure your organization understands they need to go in and fix it correctly.

You should make sure you log the details of a detected attack with a distinct error code and other information (IP address, input, user...).  This is where you want to highlight attacks.  Make sure your logging protects against SQL injections, XSS....